# How to align a primitive checkbox with the center of QHeaderView's column header?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qheaderview

I have a custom `QTableView` model with a custom `QHeaderView` in order to render a checkbox used to perform a "select all" function on the table's contents.

In my header's overloaded `paintSection()` function, I successfully render the checkbox used to select all with:

```
QStyleOptionButton option;
option.rect = QRect(3,10,16,16);
option.state = QStyle::State_Enabled | QStyle::State_Active;
if (isChecked_)
    option.state |= QStyle::State_On;
else
    option.state |= QStyle::State_Off;
style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_IndicatorCheckBox, &option, painter);
```

Unfortunately, the checkbox is *not* rendered centered, and instead justified left. This completely clashes with the properly-centered `QStyledItemDelegate` checkboxes in the column for each table entry.

I know I can change the first two args of `QRect` to change the origin of the drawn primitive, but this isn't responsive to changes in column width. Although, making the column width fixed isn't the worst solution.

How can I properly center the checkbox in the column header?

Ancillary question: the checkbox in the header is able to be toggled by clicking *anywhere* in the cell, not just on the box itself (unlike those rendered in the table via delegates). Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I have a solution for your second question as well, but following the rule for one question per post, I suggest you to ask it separately. You could post a link to this question to cover the common details. There it is important to explain how you set/reset `isChecked_`.

Comment: Thanks! Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52640263/only-toggling-primitive-checkbox-in-qheaderview-when-directly-clicked-not-anywh

Comment: @Answoquest Did my solution work for you?

Comment: @eyllanesc computer is in another state until tomorrow, I'll implement your solution when I get back and let you know!

Comment: @Answoquest Okay, but always remember to give feedback so that you can solve any problem. :-)

Comment: @Answoquest, I think it is time to accept the answer of eyllanesc. You might as well consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The solution of @scopchanov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52626397/6622587) does not work for me since the checkbox covers the whole item of the header

[image]
[image]

A possible solution is to draw the CheckBox with styles, but apart from that you have to keep a memory of whether the element is checked or not, for this we use `QMap<>`, the first element is the `logicalIndex` since it does not change even when it is move the columns and the second element is the state.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QHeaderView>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QTableView>

class CheckedHeaderView : public QHeaderView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QHeaderView::QHeaderView;
protected:
    void paintSection(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect, int logicalIndex) const override
    {
        painter->save();
        QHeaderView::paintSection(painter, rect, logicalIndex);
        painter->restore();
        QStyleOptionButton opt;

        QRect checkbox_rect = style()->subElementRect(QStyle::SE_CheckBoxIndicator, &opt);
        checkbox_rect.moveCenter(rect.center());
        opt.rect = checkbox_rect;
        opt.state = QStyle::State_Enabled | QStyle::State_Active;
        if(logicalIndex == columnDown)
            opt.state |= QStyle::State_Sunken;
        if (states[logicalIndex])
            opt.state |= QStyle::State_On;
        else
            opt.state |= QStyle::State_Off;
        style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_IndicatorCheckBox, &opt, painter);
    }
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override
    {
        QHeaderView::mousePressEvent(event);
        int li = logicalIndexAt(event->pos());
        if(li == -1) return;
        columnDown = li;
        updateSection(li);
    }
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override
    {
        QHeaderView::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
        int li = logicalIndexAt(event->pos());
        if(li == -1) return;
        states[li] = !states[li];
        Q_EMIT checked(li, states[li]);
        columnDown = -1;
        updateSection(li);
    }
Q_SIGNALS:
    void checked(int logicalIndex, bool state);
private:
    QMap<int, bool> states;
    int columnDown = -1;
};

class TableView : public QTableView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TableView(QWidget *parent = nullptr):
        QTableView(parent)
    {
        CheckedHeaderView *header = new CheckedHeaderView(Qt::Horizontal, this);
        setHorizontalHeader(header);
        connect(header, &CheckedHeaderView::checked, this, &TableView::on_checked);
    }
private Q_SLOTS:
    void on_checked(int logicalIndex, bool state){
        QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlags command = state? QItemSelectionModel::Select : QItemSelectionModel::Deselect;
        for(int r=0; r < model()->rowCount(); r++){
            QModelIndex ix = model()->index(r, logicalIndex);
            selectionModel()->select(ix, command);
        }
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    TableView w;
    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(8, 6, &w);
    w.setModel(model);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, `QStyle::subElementRect` is better than the whole `rect`, passed to `QHeaderView::paintSection`.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

[`QHeaderView::paintSection`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#paintSection) takes a `QRect &rect` as an argument. Set [`QStyleOption::rect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoption.html#rect-var) to be equal to `rect`, i.e. replace

```
option.rect = QRect(3,10,16,16);
```

with

```
option.rect = rect;
```

**Note:** This solution is responsive to changes in column width.

## Example

Using your implementation of `paintSection` I have created a minimal example in order to demonstrate how the proposed solution could be implemented. The code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/scopchanov/SO-CustomTableHeader).

## Result

The provided example produces the following result on Windows 7:

[image: Windows 7 - Window with a checkbox in the header of a table with three rows]

The result on Windows 10:

[image: Windows 10 - Window with a checkbox in the header of a table with three rows]

**Note:** This solution does not work on Linux, as it produces the following result (Ubuntu 17):

[image: Ubuntu 17 - Window with a checkbox in the header of a table with three rows]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Unfortunately, this solution expands the checkbox to fill the entire header cell: https://i.imgur.com/uq776aQ.png

Comment: @Answoquest, I am afraid I have to disagree with you. Did you check the minimal example I have provided on Github? The result is shown in the picture and the checkbox is drawn correctly. Why it does not work in your project is a separate issue, so again I would suggest you to mark the question as accepted (you might as well consider upvoting it), as it answers the question from the title in the generic case (this is important for the future readers) and post a new question why this solution does not work in your specific case, providing enough details (mcve) to identify the problem.

Comment: @Answoquest i would be more than happy to look for a solution. I will take a look at your other question too.

Comment: Your GitHub code results are the same: https://i.imgur.com/tZorpal.png . In your screenshot it looks like you're using an older version of Windows.

Comment: @Answoquest, I am on the go now. I will test the code later under Windows 10 and Ubuntu and I will get back to you with the results.

Comment: @scopchanov I tried it in Arch Linux and I get inappropriate behavior as the images show in my answer

Comment: @Answoquest, I am primarily working under Windows 7. There it looked OK, so I didn't investigate further. Testing it on Windows 10 shows a similar result, but the problem is revealed once it is tested on Linux. Anyway, the solution by eyllanesc is the correct one, so I suggest you to accept it (if you like his answer, you might as well consider upvoting it).